# Getting Google Spreadsheet CSV into A Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

I uploaded a file to Google spreadsheets (to make a publically accessible example IPython Notebook, with data) I was using the file in it's native form could be read into a Pandas Dataframe. So now I use the following code to read the spreadsheet, works fine but just comes in as string,, and I'm not having any luck trying to get it back into a dataframe (you can get the data)

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv')
data = r.content
```

The data ends up looking like: (1st row headers)

```
',City,region,Res_Comm,mkt_type,Quradate,National_exp,Alabama_exp,Sales_exp,Inventory_exp,Price_exp,Credit_exp\n0,Dothan,South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan,Residential,Rural,1/15/2010,2,2,3,2,3,3\n10,Foley,South_Mobile-Baldwin,Residential,Suburban_Urban,1/15/2010,4,4,4,4,4,3\n12,Birmingham,North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston,Commercial,Suburban_Urban,1/15/2010,2,2,3,2,2,3\n
```

The native pandas code that brings in the disk resident file looks like:

```
df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('/home/tom/Dropbox/Projects/annonallanswerswithmaster1012013.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=['Quradate'])
```

A "clean" solution would be helpful to many to provide an easy way to share datasets for Pandas use! I tried a bunch of alternative with no success and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious again.

Just a Update note The new Google spreadsheet has a different URL pattern Just use this in place of the URL in the above example and or the below answer and you should be fine here is an example:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177_dFZ0i-duGxLiyg6tnwNDKruAYE-_Dd8vAQziipJQ/export?format=csv&id
```

see solution below from @Max Ghenis which just used pd.read_csv, no need for StringIO or requests...

Comment: how did you get the `csv` link from drive to begin with?

Comment: Just open the spreadsheet in your browser and copy the URL

Comment: the URL ends with `/edit?ts=5c0e311e#gid=0` and the sharing link ends with `/edit?usp=sharing`, none have `csv` and both give `404` when requested by pandas code

Comment: use the download as csv on the docs menus

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `read_csv()` on a `StringIO` object:

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv')
data = r.content
    
In [10]: df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data), index_col=0,parse_dates=['Quradate'])

In [11]: df.head()
Out[11]: 
          City                                            region     Res_Comm  \
0       Dothan  South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan  Residential   
10       Foley                              South_Mobile-Baldwin  Residential   
12  Birmingham      North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston   Commercial   
38       Brent      North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston  Residential   
44      Athens                 North_Huntsville-Decatur-Florence  Residential   

          mkt_type            Quradate  National_exp  Alabama_exp  Sales_exp  \
0            Rural 2010-01-15 00:00:00             2            2          3   
10  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             4            4          4   
12  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             2            2          3   
38           Rural 2010-01-15 00:00:00             3            3          3   
44  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             4            5          4   

    Inventory_exp  Price_exp  Credit_exp  
0               2          3           3  
10              4          4           3  
12              2          2           3  
38              3          3           2  
44              4          4           4
```

Comment: I was looking for weeks how to import a spreadsheet into pandas. never heard of requests or StringIO libraries. Thank you!!

Comment: Note the new URL format in the bottom of the original question above it is needed for the new Google spreadsheet version

Comment: To clarify "got moved around in python3 if you're using that":

from io import StringIO

Comment: Thanks! But I had to use this form of google url for csv output: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23702001/507544

Comment: How can one specify the sheet (i.e. `#gid=x` in URL)? Adding it to the URL itself after `key=` didn't work.

Comment: see solution below! from @Max Ghenis

Comment: Since support for Python 2 will be removed, I updated the code to something that's forward-compatible with Python 3. Basically, used BytesIO instead of StringIO. But Max's answer below mentioned that you don't actually need the IO buffers.

Answer (score 86):

Seems to work for me without the `StringIO`:

```
test = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + 
                   '0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc' +
                   '/export?gid=0&format=csv',
                   # Set first column as rownames in data frame
                   index_col=0,
                   # Parse column values to datetime
                   parse_dates=['Quradate']
                  )
test.head(5)  # Same result as @TomAugspurger
```

BTW, including the `?gid=` enables importing different sheets, find the gid in the URL.

Comment: Maybe just add comments as to what index_col and parse_dates do?  Also, maybe this is obvious, but I think this only works if the Spreadsheet is public; I believe if it's not, you'll have to use the API.

Comment: Great solution. Works when a sheet is shared as "Anyone on the Internet with this link can view". Note that `index_col` and `parse_dates` arguments are optional.

Comment: it only works when the SPREADSHEET IS PUBLIC

Answer (score 22):

Open the specific sheet you want in your browser. Make sure it's at least viewable by anyone with the link. Copy and paste the URL. You'll get something like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/BLAHBLAHBLAH/edit#gid=NUMBER`.

```
sheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/BLAHBLAHBLAH/edit#gid=NUMBER'
```

First we turn that into a CSV export URL, like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/BLAHBLAHBLAH/export?format=csv&gid=NUMBER`:

```
csv_export_url = sheet_url.replace('/edit#gid=', '/export?format=csv&gid=')
```

Then we pass it to [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which can take a URL.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_export_url)
```

This will break if Google changes its API (it seems undocumented), and may give unhelpful errors if a network failure occurs.

Comment: This code returns a HTML page for download the csv, not the csv file from gsheet.

Comment: I am getting ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

Comment: Did you make sure access is set to "anyone with the link"

Answer (score 12):

My approach is a bit different. I just used pandas.Dataframe() but obviously needed to install and import gspread. And it worked fine!

```
gsheet = gs.open("Name")
Sheet_name ="today"
wsheet = gsheet.worksheet(Sheet_name)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())
```

Comment: Nice..The interface keeps getting cleaner!

Comment: just to clarify, `gs` would be `gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)`

Answer (score 7):

I have been using the following utils and it worked so far:

```
def load_from_gspreadsheet(sheet_name, key):
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}&headers=1'.format(
        key=key, sheet_name=sheet_name.replace(' ', '%20'))

    log.info('Loading google spreadsheet from {}'.format(url))

    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    return df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Unnamed')], axis=1)
```

You must specify the sheet_name and the key. The key is the string you get from the url in the following path: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/edit/`.

You can change the value of headers if you have more than one row for the column names but I am not sure if it still work with multi-headers.

It may brake if Google will change their APIs.

Also please bear in mind that your spreadsheet must be public, everyone with the link can read it.

Answer (score 6):

First

- Click on File
- Select Publish to the web tab
- Select which sheet you want as CSV(in case of multiple sheet) and also change the format from webpage to Comma-separated values
- Click on publish
- Copy the link eg: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/{}/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/%7B%7D/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/{}/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv")
```

Comment: underrated but simple answer.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! But this reads only the first sheet. How could I read all the sheets?

Answer (score 5):

Straight to the point:

- Get your google URL

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ **this is your sheet ID number**/edit?gid=**This will be your tab name, it will be a number. Each tab has its own**

I like to make a function(not making here) so I separate my variables

- sheet_id = "Place your sheet ID here"
- sheet_name = "Place your sheet # here"

#### the next URL is the tricky part:

```py
url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?gid={sheet_name}&format=csv"
```

## Then just read it in

**df = pd.csv(url)**

That's it. If you need to select a different row as a header you can do this

df = pd.csv(url, header=1)

Comment: use "df = pd.read_csv(url)" instead of "df = pd.csv(url)".

Comment: Great point @RobbDunlap I can not remember why I used pd.csv and not put "read" in there.

Answer (score 3):

If the csv file was shared via drive and not via spreadsheet then the below change to the url would work

```
#Derive the id from the google drive shareable link.
#For the file at hand the link is as below
#<https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-tjNjMP6w0RUV4GhJWw08ql3wYwsNU69>
file_id='1-tjNjMP6w0RUV4GhJWw08ql3wYwsNU69'
link='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={FILE_ID}'
csv_url=link.format(FILE_ID=file_id)
#The final url would be as below:-
#csv_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-tjNjMP6w0RUV4GhJWw08ql3wYwsNU69'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
```

And the dataframe would be (if you just ran the above code)

```
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9   10  11
3   12  13  14  15
```

See working code [here](https://repl.it/@bulbus/FairOldlaceArray).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```py
import pandas as pd

#Create a public URL
#https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc/edit?usp=sharing

#get spreadsheets key from url
gsheetkey = "0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc"

#sheet name
sheet_name = 'Sheet 1'

url=f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key={gsheetkey}&output=xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(url,sheet_name=sheet_name)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Google Sheets file go to File > Publish to the web > Select .csv (see screenshot) > Copy link

[Google Sheets: Publish to web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZOdh.png)

Code

```py
import pandas as pd

path = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSvmELTzIjfSmX8GuV3HE2qomN3uRyvPX8RDzpw77JH33DUbj1bjech7H6NYPArvpZFux0DdJ5L5TKy/pub?output=csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path)
print(data)
```

[Code in Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyrBw.png)