# Loading a generic Google Spreadsheet in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gdata

When I try to load a Google Spreadsheet in pandas

```
from StringIO import StringIO  
import requests
r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=<some_long_code>&output=csv')
data = r.content
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0)
```

I get the following:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1316 fields in line 73, saw 1386
```

Why? I would think that one could identify the spreadsheet set of rows and columns with data and use the spreadsheets rows and columns as the dataframe index and columns respectively (with NaN for anything empty). Why does it fail?

Comment: Can you post the error line of data, are the fields delimited correctly? This is usually the source of these errors

Comment: Are you sure that that url even *returns* the data in an accessible format?  It's not like it's producing an HTML table to be parsed.

Comment: Don't you need a "&output=csv" at the end of your request?  See also [google spreadsheet pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611729/getting-google-spreadsheet-csv-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question of mine shows how [Getting Google Spreadsheet CSV into A Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611729/getting-google-spreadsheet-csv-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

As one of the commentators noted you have not asked for the data in CSV format you have the "edit" request at the end of the url
You can use this code and see it work on the spreadsheet (which by the way needs to be public..) It is possible to do private sheets as well but that is another topic.

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # got moved around in python3 if you're using that.

import requests
r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv')
data = r.content

In [10]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0,parse_dates=['Quradate'])

In [11]: df.head()
Out[11]: 
          City                                            region     Res_Comm  \
0       Dothan  South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan  Residential   
10       Foley                              South_Mobile-Baldwin  Residential   
12  Birmingham      North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston   Commercial   
38       Brent      North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston  Residential   
44      Athens                 North_Huntsville-Decatur-Florence  Residential   

          mkt_type            Quradate  National_exp  Alabama_exp  Sales_exp  \
0            Rural 2010-01-15 00:00:00             2            2          3   
10  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             4            4          4   
12  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             2            2          3   
38           Rural 2010-01-15 00:00:00             3            3          3   
44  Suburban_Urban 2010-01-15 00:00:00             4            5          4
```

The new Google spreadsheet url format for getting the csv output is

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177_dFZ0i-duGxLiyg6tnwNDKruAYE-_Dd8vAQziipJQ/export?format=csv&id
```

Well they changed the url format slightly again now you need:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177_dFZ0i-duGxLiyg6tnwNDKruAYE-_Dd8vAQziipJQ/export?format=csv&gid=0 #for the 1st sheet
```

I also found I needed to do the following to deal with Python 3 a slight revision to the above:

```
from io import StringIO
```

and to get the file:

```
guid=0 #for the 1st sheet
act = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177_dFZ0i-duGxLiyg6tnwNDKruAYE-_Dd8vAQziipJQ/export?format=csv&gid=%s' % guid)
dataact = act.content.decode('utf-8') #To convert to string for Stringio
actdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dataact),index_col=0,parse_dates=[0], thousands=',').sort()
```

actdf is now a full pandas dataframe with headers (column names)

Comment: Thanks @dartdog I just updated the link so that it includes `key=` and `&output=csv` at the end, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you use something like (see the full expansion of this URL (it is the same as from the code above) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv in the browser Google should download a csv.. IF not read up there Check and post your error from the browser By the way there may be a slightly different code for the new spreadsheet version, have not tried with that. I did see it referred to somewhere but the general principal should hold once you have the url working in the browser..

Comment: See edit a the end of the post above:: Here is the new format for New version of Google spreadsheets in CSV You will have to copy and paste it to see it entirely (leave off the (" I just used that to try to force SO to show it all, did not work!) ("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177_dFZ0i-duGxLiyg6tnwNDKruAYE-_Dd8vAQziipJQ/export?format=csv&id")

Comment: new ending for New format Google spreadsheets export?format=csv&id see above end of post

Comment: Thanks! -- I will try that, although I am surprised to see that your query works and mine (i.e. with my URL) doesn't

Comment: you may have permission issues need to publish and share the sheet publicly And note that the earlier version of the url is quite different at the front as well as the rear!

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** this solution will make your data accessible by anyone.

In google sheet click file>publish to web. Then select what do you need to publish and select export format .csv. You'll have the link something like:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<your sheets key yhere>/pub?gid=1317664180&single=true&output=csv`

Then simply:

```py
import pandas as pd
pathtoCsv = r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheets key>/pub?gid=1317664180&single=true&output=csv'
dev = pd.read_csv(pathtoCsv)
print dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you share the sheet?

- Click the “Share” button in the top-right corner of your document.
- Click on the “Get link” section and pick “Anyone with the link”.

This solved for me the problem.

If you didn't share, Google Sheet returns an errorpage what causes the Panda-error. (The fact that the URL works and returns a CSV when opening/pasting in the browser is because you are logged in)

Answer (score -1):

The current Google Drive URL to export as csv is:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=EnterIDHere

So:

```
import pandas as pd
pathtocsv = r'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=EnterIDHere'
df = pd.read_csv(pathtocsv)
```