# Google Service Account Not able to edit / update a Google Sheet using gspread

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, gspread

This is a follow up to this StackOverFlow question.

[In python, is it possible to edit a publicy shared google sheet, without an auth code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562037/in-python-is-it-possible-to-edit-a-publicy-shared-google-sheet-without-an-auth?noredirect=1#comment105339314_59562037)

Which advices to use a g-suite service account to access google sheets.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('### downloaded JSON file ###', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sht1 = gc.open_by_key('1wj9L7Hn779GKP0s4MblkU1wHcqaVcG_E2YKAo1vdof0')
```

I have done this and I am able to read values from the sheet just fine.

```
#Open by Gdrive ID
worksheet1 = gc.open_by_key('1qlIZAAK32fTb20KeOr9f-TAxYz7yQnvHUsdGP9Iakrc').sheet1
worksheet1.col_values(3)

>['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

But when I try to update a cell, I am getting a permission denied error.

```
query = 'insert this'
worksheet1.update_cell(len(values_list)+1, 3, query)
```

This is the output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9e7f86cb0411> in <module>()
----> 1 worksheet1.update_cell(len(values_list)+1, 3, query)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gspread/models.py in update_cell(self, row, col, value)
    737             },
    738             body={
--> 739                 'values': [[value]]
    740             }
    741         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gspread/models.py in values_update(self, range, params, body)
    174         """
    175         url = SPREADSHEET_VALUES_URL % (self.id, quote(range))
--> 176         r = self.client.request('put', url, params=params, json=body)
    177         return r.json()
    178 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
     77             return response
     78         else:
---> 79             raise APIError(response)
     80 
     81     def list_spreadsheet_files(self):

APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

#### Details and what I tried so far.

My service account uses the same email as the google drive account which I am using to host my google sheets. So I should be able to edit a sheet from my service account.

Comment: Your service account does not use the same email address. A service account is an identity. Use your user credentials to generate credentials. An alternate is to add the service account identity to your account (drive/sheets) with permission.

Comment: I looking how to do the later, but I am not able to find anything. I am only able to add an email to a sheet, but my GCP already uses the same email

Comment: Can I ask you whether the service account is shared with the Spreadsheet as the writer? And when you share the service account with the Spreadsheet, please use the value of `client_email` in the credential file of the service account as the email. It's like `###@###.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. How about this?

Comment: A service account has an email address also, just like your user account.