# Getting public Google sheets as panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I have been trying to obtain the `Statewise` sheet from this public googlesheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#) as a python dataframe.

The URL of this sheet is different from the URL of other examples for achieving the goal of getting sheet as dataframe, seen on this website.

**URL is this :** 
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#`

**One standard way maybe the following,**

```
import pandas

googleSheetId = '<Google Sheets Id>'
worksheetName = '<Sheet Name>'
URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{0}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={1}'.format(
    googleSheetId,
    worksheetName
)

df = pandas.read_csv(URL)
print(df)
```

But in the present URL I do not see a structure used here. Can someone help to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: check this package : [gspread-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-pandas/) it might be helpful in connecting with google spreadsheets

Comment: @sammywemmy : It apppears that gspread is for private google sheets. Thus requiring authorization.

Comment: my bad. check out J-H 's solution then. Also check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611857/7175713)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google spreadsheet is actually an html thing. So you should use `read_html` to load it into a list of pandas dataframes:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf8')
```

if lxml is available or, if you use BeautifulSoup4:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url, flavor='bs4', encoding='utf8')
```

You will get a list of dataframes and for example `dfs[0]` is:

```
     0   1                                                  2                3
0    1  id                                             Banner  Number_Of_Times
1    2   1  Don't Hoard groceries and essentials. Please e...                2
2    3   2  Be compassionate! Help those in need like the ...                2
3    4   3  Be considerate : While buying essentials remem...                2
4    5   4  Going out to buy essentials? Social Distancing...                2
5    6   5  Plan ahead! Take a minute and check how much y...                2
6    7   6  Plan and calculate your essential needs for th...                2
7    8   7  Help out the elderly by bringing them their gr...                2
8    9   8  Help out your workers and domestic help by not...                2
9   10   9  Lockdown means LOCKDOWN! Avoid going out unles...                1
10  11  10           Panic mode : OFF! ❌ESSENTIALS ARE ON! ✔️                1
11  12  11  Do not panic! ❌ Your essential needs will be t...                1
12  13  12  Be a true Indian. Show compassion. Be consider...                1
13  14  13  If you have symptoms and suspect you have coro...                1
14  15  14  Stand Against FAKE News and WhatsApp Forwards!...                1
15  16  15  If you have any queries, Reach out to your dis...                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests

r = requests.get(URL)
data = r.content

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data), index_col=0, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Already tried this. I get the error : `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 48, saw 20` Here we do not specify the sheet hence I do not know which sheet is being obtained.

Comment: You can try adding error_bad_lines=False parameter, but maybe something with your xsl file is not okay

Comment: I tried that as well. I am not accessing the correct worksheet hence some other data comes in.